# Name of the role that is neither primary nor support, similar to the dodging guy in Mummy Returns?

Tags: reference, trope

In *The Mummy Returns*, there is a henchman that gets lucky number of times when he dodges a blade/shot meant for him, just to watch another henchman behind him take the hit.

Is there a name for such characters that play a non-essential role but yet add quite a flair to scenes?

In each scene where he dodges the inevitable it is quite noticeable yet the actor never says a line until his demise, where he is paired with a luckier one than him and his luck runs out.

Comment: My first instinct is "comedy relief" but it's not quite on point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a few tropes are in effect here, though I can't find a single term that encompasses all of them.

He is lucky that he's wearing [Plot Armor](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlotArmor) that protects him from the other bad guys.

The element of luck is [Lampshaded](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LampshadeHanging) because it's always noticeable.

And yet his luck runs out in the end, which could be an example of [Chekhov's Gag](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ChekhovsGag):

The fact that this secondary character keeps getting lucky needs to have a payoff, otherwise why should the audience care, over, and over again? By killing him, the joke (I guess is) that his luck ran out.

As a side note, it reminds me of a similar moment in *Saving Private Ryan* where a soldier takes a shot to his helmet, and others comment on how lucky he was/is. He then takes off his helmet and is promptly shot again, this time fatally. Similar to *The Mummy*, there was a setup and a pay-off.

**I think ultimately, he's just an [Unlucky Extra](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UnluckyExtra).**

Comment: Damn good answer, Chekhov's Gag reminded me of this joke in Sopranos : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TynPqDlQ-F0 .